# AngularJS best approach: data driven or event driven?

Tags: angularjs

AngularJS is famous of the '3d': data binding, dependency injection and directives. As data binding is such a nature of angularJS application, I always assume data-driven is the best approach when making decision on how the app works.

For example, if I want to respond to some property updates, I will $watch on that property and write call back functions for it. And if I can use angularJS properly, there is no $apply required and the two way data binding will automatically do the magic with the great digest cycles.

However, in jQuery or many other JavaScript libraries, event-driven seems to be so common that people always think this is how client side should work. Event-driven approach in angularJS, on the other hand, means I need to $emit or $broadcast events across directives/controllers to throw events here and there. This is somehow different to the data-driven approach.

My idea is event-driven makes the whole application hard to debug, understand and maintain. The only reason I use it is because it's easy to pass data across scopes, when the nested scopes themselves are too complicated to do so.

Any idea on this? When should we stick to data-driven and when should we use event driven? What is the best approach in general?